# overflow on main page instead of carousel section

Tags: css, flexbox, grid, overflow

I want to have a fully responsive page for mobile devices , and there is a semi carousel slider that i wanna it have `overflow` .
but i have horizontal overflow on page instead of carousel section.
i don't want to have overflow on my main page 
why overflow be applied to html document ??

**resize the code , below 530 px to appear `overflow`**

```css
main{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr;
  gap: 2rem;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
section{
  background: gold;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  gap: 1rem;
}
.box{
  width: 50%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding:2rem;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </section>
  <section>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </section>
  <section>  <!--  carousel section -->
    <div class="container"> 
      <div class="box">
        <h4>lorem</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vitae nulla diam in ac </p>
        <div>
          <img src="#" alt="image">
          <div>
            <h4>lorem</h4>
            <p>lorem</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">another box</div>
      <div class="box">another box</div>
      <div class="box">another box</div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </section>
  <section>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: try inserting `display: grid;` inside *<section>*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a complete answer for my question in this [article](https://ishadeed.com/article/defensive-css/#minimum-content-size-in-css-grid) from [Ahmad Shadeed](https://ishadeed.com)

### Minimum content size in CSS grid

CSS grid has a default minimum content size for its child items which is `auto`. That means, if there is an element that is larger than the grid item, it will overflow.

To fix that, we have three different solutions:

1. Using `minmax()`

> `grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr)` for my problem.

2. Applying `min-width = 0` to the grid items
3. Adding `overflow: hidden` to the grid items

i added all three sulotions to below snippet and you can use each one separately.

---

```css
main{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr);  /*  first ssolution */
  gap: 2rem;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
section{
  background: gold;
  min-width: 0; /*  second  ssolution */ 
  overflow: hidden; /*  third  ssolution */
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  gap: 1rem;
}
.box{
  width: 50%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding:2rem;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </section>
  <section>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </section>
  <section>  <!--  carousel section -->
    <div class="container"> 
      <div class="box">
        <h4>lorem</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vitae nulla diam in ac </p>
        <div>
          <img src="#" alt="image">
          <div>
            <h4>lorem</h4>
            <p>lorem</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">another box</div>
      <div class="box">another box</div>
      <div class="box">another box</div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </section>
  <section>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: I'm glad you want to share some knowledge, but, this doesn't actually solve your own problem: **1.** You don't have any values for the `minmax()`, also you said *"fully responsive..."*, this makes it *"less"* responsive; **2.** Applying `min-width = 0` doesn't work (the `container` will overflow again); **3.** The `overflow: hidden` doesn't actually prevent the overflow, it just makes part of the carousel and its scrollbar invisible (here you break usability). The actual problem was a simple misunderstanding about the fraction unit and its behavior.

Comment: I think it is not nice to unaccept a valid answer to accept a non-valid one :/

Comment: @Leo Yes you are right and I had to add the answer completely. Now I will happy to you take a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it by just setting the width of the column to `100%` instead of `1fr`.

By using `1fr`, the fraction size will take the biggest element's width, in your case, the carousel's width, that's why it overflows.

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  gap: 2rem;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

section {
  background: gold;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.box {
  width: 50%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding: 2rem;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </section>
  <section>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </section>
  <section class="carousel-section">
    <!--  carousel section -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box">
        <h4>lorem</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vitae nulla diam in ac </p>
        <div>
          <img src="#" alt="image">
          <div>
            <h4>lorem</h4>
            <p>lorem</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">another box</div>
      <div class="box">another box</div>
      <div class="box">another box</div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </section>
  <section>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

I added CSS grid to your `<section>`

```css
section {
    display: grid;
    /* your code*/
}
```

[image]

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  gap: 2rem;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

section {
  background: gold;
  display: grid;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.box {
  width: 50%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding: 2rem;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <!-- 1 lorem -->
  <section>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</section>
  <!-- 2 lorem -->
  <section>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</section>

  <!-- 3 -->
  <section>
    <!--  carousel section -->
    <div class="container">
      <!-- 1 box -->
      <div class="box">
        <h4>lorem</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vitae nulla diam in ac </p>
        <div>
          <img src="#" alt="image">
          <div>
            <h4>lorem</h4>
            <p>lorem</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- 2 box -->
      <div class="box">another box</div>
      <!-- 3 box -->
      <div class="box">another box</div>
      <!-- 4 box -->
      <div class="box">another box</div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- 4 lorem -->
  <section>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</section>
  <!-- 5 lorem -->
  <section>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your grid into flex to prevent overflowing

```
main{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 2rem;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Comment: i need grid system.